# Displaying thumbnail on web page but show larger image in modal via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I have a large list of thumbnails on a web page, and I want to use a modal to display a larger version of the thumbnail when a user clicks on it.

The file name for the thumbnail is the same as the larger image name - but with _thumb inserted.  For example, the larger image file name is 123456_1.jpg - and the thumbnail file name is 123456_1_thumb.jpg.

I have followed this code -> https://jsfiddle.net/dmvshn/75ueLgbt/ to get the modal working (and it works).  But, I can't figure out how to use thumbnails instead of the actual larger images.

I was thinking that I could display the thumbnail image file name on the page - example: 123456_1_thumb.jpg - but then when I click on the thumbnail image, JavaScript could just remove the "_thumb" in the image name and then it would display the larger image - i.e. 123456_1_thumb.jpg becomes 123456_1.jpg.

Here is the JavaScript code from the above link:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = $('.myImg');
var modalImg = $("#img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
$('.myImg').click(function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    var newSrc = this.src;
    modalImg.attr('src', newSrc);
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
});

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

I have tried other methods of using onclick to display a different image in the modal but I can't get it to work either. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need to replace this line:
var newSrc = this.src;

for this:
var newSrc = this.src.replace('_thumb','');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `replace()` function on the the string:

```
var newSrc = this.src.replace(/_thumb/, "");
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  You are a genius and a scholar.  May your children be beautiful and grow up to be wealthy.  Thank you very much!